# FilePicker return null nbytes for large file

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app for Web.
It allows user picking multiple files and uploading on Google Storage.

```
FilePickerResult? picked = await FilePicker.platform
    .pickFiles(allowMultiple: true,
               type: FileType.custom,
               withData: true,
               allowedExtensions: ['mp4', 'avi', 'MP4']);

if (picked != null) {
   for (var i = 0; i < picked.files.length; i++) {
       var file = picked.files[i];
       Uint8List? pickedInBytes = file.bytes!;
       
       Reference ref = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref()
                          .child('data')
                          .child(file.name);

       final metadata = SettableMetadata(contentType: 'video/mp4');
       uploadTask = ref.putData(pickedInBytes, metadata);
   }


}
```

The above code works for small videos but fails for large video (4GB) because file.bytes is for some reasons null in this case .
I tried to add withData: true as suggested in other Stackoverflow issues but it did not work. Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: on what device you're testing?

Comment: On web. Flutter run, Chrome. It is a web app